# Converting Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm having trouble converting a section of MatLab code into Python. The following is the MatLab code;

```
    sig1 = 1;
    xi_t = zeros(size(t));
    [min_dif, array_pos_start] = min(abs(t -t(1)  ));
    [min_dif, array_pos_stop ] = min(abs(t -t(end)/2));
    p_len = [0: (t(2))-t(1) : ( t(array_pos_stop) - t(array_pos_start))];
    xi_t(array_pos_start:array_pos_stop)= sqrt(sig1)*exp((sig1/2)*p_len);
    norm = trapz(t,xi_t.*conj(xi_t));
    xi = xi_t/sqrt(norm);
```

Where

```
dt = 1e-2;       % time step
t = [0:dt:7-dt]; % t
```

I have attempted the following Conversion, but does not work.

```
from numpy import * 
from matplotlib import *

dt=0.01
t=[arange_(0,7 - dt,dt)]

sig1=1
xi_t=zeros(size(t))
min_dif, array_pos_start = min(abs(t - t[0],nargout=2)
min_dif, array_pos_stop = min(abs(t - (t[-1]) / 2),nargout=2)
p_len=[arange_(0,(t(array_pos_stop) - t(array_pos_start)),(t[1]) - t[0])]
xi_t[arange_(array_pos_start,array_pos_stop)]=sqrt(sig1) * exp((sig1 / 2) * p_len)
norm=trapz(t,xi_t.dot(conj(xi_t)))
xi=xi_t / sqrt(norm)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think we need a bit more info: what the purpose of the MATLAB code is, some example output, where your Python code is throwing errors, etc. Also, are you using pylab? If you have a line like `from pylab import *` in your code it's best to include that as well.

Comment: What Python libraries are you using to facilitate this conversoin?  I have a hunch it's `numpy`.  However, we can't even begin to help you until you tell us what libraries you're using.  Some of those functions are not part of the standard Python distribution.

Comment: Ok, so this is the current error;


    ' min_dif, array_pos_stop = min(abs(t - (t(-1) / 2),nargout=2)
          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax'


Using both these libraries;


from numpy import *
from matplotlib import *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to note about `MATLAB` vs. `Python`.

First, never do `from foo import *`.  This can lead to collisions and unexpected behaviour.  Generally it is better `import foo`, `from foo import bar`, or `import foobar as fo`.

Second, ranges in `MATLAB` include the end, while those in `Python` do not, so manually excluding the last element like you do will make it shorter than you expect.  Also, with `Python` ranges, you don't need to specify the start if it is `0`.

Third, the `size` in `numpy` is the size of the array (so the total number of elements).  The equivalent of the `MATLAB` `size` in `numpy` is `shape`.  You can use the `numpy` `shape` function, but it is generally better to use the `shape` property, which is like a function attached to the array itself, which is obtained for an array `arr` by `arr.shape`.

Similarly, you can get the `min`, `max`, and other such properties using `arr.min()`, `arr.max()`, etc.  There is also no `nargout` option, just use `arr.argmin()` and `arr.argmax()` to get the minimum and maximum indices.

Fourth, there is a useful function, `np.zeros_like`, which makes an array of all zeros with the same shape and type as the given array.  There is also a corresponding `ones_like` and `full_like` (the latter being for `np.full`, which creates an array filled with an arbitrary value).

Fifth, in the `numpy` version of `trapz`, `y` comes first and `x` comes second, while in the `MATLAB` version it is the opposite.  You can keep this straight by using named arguments, such as `np.trapz(x=x, y=y)` (order doesn't matter when you do this).  This is not possible in `MATLAB` at all.

Sixth, you can slice in `Python` like you do in `MATLAB`, you don't need to use a range.

Seventh, in both `Python` and `MATLAB`, it is generally better to avoid using ranges with float values.  This is due to inherent inaccuracies with floats.  `linspace` is better.

Finally, you don't need to surround you ranges with `[]`.  It makes a list of an array, which you don't want.

So here is your `MATLAB` code ported to `Python`, using the above tips.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt = 0.01
t = np.linspace(0, 7, 7/0.01, endpoint=False)
# same as, but safer than:
# np.arange(0, 7, 0.01)
# you should do this sort of thing on matlab, too

sig1 = 1
xi_t = np.zeros_like(t)
array_pos_start = abs(t-t[0]).argmin()
array_pos_stop = abs(t-t[-1]/2).argmax()
p_len = np.linspace(0, t[array_pos_stop]-t[array_pos_start], array_pos_stop-array_pos_start)
xi_t[array_pos_start:array_pos_stop] = np.exp(p_len*sig1/2)*np.sqrt(sig1)
norm = np.trapz(y=xi_t.dot(xi_t.conj()), x=t)
xi = xi_t/np.sqrt(norm)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def _min(x):
    return [np.amin(x), np.argmin(x)]

dt = 1e-2;                      # time step
t = np.arange(0, 7, dt)         # t

sig1 = 1;
xi_t = np.zeros(len(t));
[min_dif, array_pos_start] = _min(abs(t -t[0] ));
[min_dif, array_pos_stop ] = _min(abs(t -t[-1]/2.0));
step = t[1]-t[0]
p_len = np.arange(0, t[array_pos_stop] - t[array_pos_start] + step, step)
xi_t[array_pos_start:array_pos_stop+1] = math.sqrt(sig1) * np.exp((sig1/2.0)*p_len);
norm = np.trapz(t, xi_t * np.conj(xi_t));
xi = xi_t/np.sqrt(abs(norm));
```

The one thing I'm not sure about is the difference between MATLAB's `trapz` and `np.trapz`.  MATLAB returns a positive number (~31), while `np.trapz` returns a negative number (~ -31).

So I'm not sure the additional `abs` in the  last line is good practice, but otherwise, the code appears the generate the same `xi` sequence.